# JavaScript - match non-ascii symbols using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, utf, non-ascii-characters

I want to match all mentioned users in comment. Example:

```js
var comment = '@Agneš, @Petar, please take a look at this';
var mentionedUsers = comment.match(/@\w+/g);

console.log(mentionedUsers)
```

I'm expecting `["@Agneš", "@Petar"]` but getting `["@Agne", "@Petar"]`. As you can see `š` symbol is not matched.

How can I match all letter symbols include non-ascii?

Comment: Make sure special characters are converted to their regular counterpart as they are they typed in the comment field, and you won't have this issue.

Comment: "special characters"? what world do you live in? they're perfectly normal Unicode letters. It's a JavaScript problem (for a little while longer).

Comment: Special character, as in anything that isn't `a-z`. Just converting the names in the comment field, the way the site you're on right now does, is by far the easiest.

Comment: You need to use `XRegExp` library.

Comment: You have to ensure that your JS source file has Unicode (UTF-8) charset. Otherwise your Regexp won't work as you expected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until ES6 support for unicode in regex is implemented, you can work around it with somehting like:

```
/@[^\s,]+/g
```

where you just list stuff that *can't be* in usernames. Next year,

```
/@\w+/gu
```

A way to make sure you don't get halves of email adresses and other cases where the @ is in the middle of a word would be to `match(/[^\s,@]*@[^\s,@]+(?=[\s,]|$)/g)` and then `filter` the results on whether they start with "@".

Comment: Although it's far from perfect. Will match parts of email adresses, and without lookbehind (which isn't supported in JavaScript either), there's not much we can do about it.

Answer (score -1):

the š is not a word character, and "w" is for word character.

Comment: In PHP, Python ``š`` is just normal utf letter. Can't believe JS still have no full utf support.